# LinkedHashMap<String, String> error

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

My code is as follows:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```

I am getting error:

> not a statement

I included `java.util.LinkedHashMap` package and am using `JDK version 4.1.2`

Comment: You haven't provided enough context. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've never even heard of a JDK version 4.1.2. Could you provide a link to the place you downloaded it?

Comment: Sorry, the correct version is J2RE 1.4.2

Comment: LinkedHashMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("src", srcPnoneNumber); // Sender's phone number with country code
parameters.put("dst", receiverPhoneNos); // Receiver's phone number with country code, The numbers are separated by "<" delimiter.
            parameters.put("text", message); // Your SMS text message
            parameters.put("method", "GET"); // The method used to call the url
            // Send the messages
            MessageResponse msgResponse = api.sendMessage(parameters);

Comment: Then the comments suggesting that you're trying to use generics with a version that doesn't support them are correct. More importantly, *why* are you using such an ancient version? And please don't dump code in comments like that - when you're asked for clarifications, you should put the information *in the question*.

Comment: (You realize that Java 1.5 / 5.0 came out in 2004, right? 1.4.2 is *massively* out of date, and it's almost certain that the JRE you're using has multiple security vulnerabilities.)

Comment: Existing project developed on 1.4.2 version, 
we are enhancing the project with new features

Comment: To my mind, updating to a modern JDK/JRE which has had all the appropriate security fixes should be your number one priority. At that point, you'll be able to use generics.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update JDK/JRE with new version

Answer (score 1):

Generics have been introduced in Java 5.

This feature (and the associated syntax) is not available in Java 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

In JDK 1.4 (4) generics were not supported yet. Avoid the <> parts:

```
LinkedHashMap parameters = new LinkedHashMap();
```